# SQL request optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have an SQL request that take 100% of my VM CPU while it's working. I wanna know how to optimize it :

```
SELECT g.name AS hostgroup
     , h.name AS hostname
     , a.host_id
     , s.display_name AS servicename
     , a.service_id
     , a.entry_time AS ack_time
     , (  SELECT ctime 
          FROM logs 
          WHERE logs.host_id = a.host_id 
          AND logs.service_id = a.service_id 
          AND logs.ctime < a.entry_time 
          AND logs.status IN (1, 2, 3) 
          AND logs.type = 1 
          ORDER BY logs.log_id DESC 
          LIMIT 1) AS start_time
     , ar.acl_res_name AS timeperiod
     , a.state AS state
     , a.author
     , a.acknowledgement_id AS ack_id
FROM centstorage.acknowledgements a
LEFT JOIN centstorage.hosts h ON a.host_id = h.host_id
LEFT JOIN centstorage.services s ON a.service_id = s.service_id
LEFT JOIN centstorage.hosts_hostgroups p ON a.host_id = p.host_id
LEFT JOIN centstorage.hostgroups g ON  g.hostgroup_id = p.hostgroup_id
LEFT JOIN centreon.hostgroup_relation hg ON a.host_id = hg.host_host_id
LEFT JOIN centreon.acl_resources_hg_relations hh ON hg.hostgroup_hg_id = hh.hg_hg_id
LEFT JOIN centreon.acl_resources ar ON hh.acl_res_id = ar.acl_res_id
WHERE ar.acl_res_name != 'All Resources'
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = MONTH(CURDATE())
AND a.service_id is not null
ORDER BY a.acknowledgement_id ASC
```

The problem is at this part :

```
(SELECT ctime FROM logs
 WHERE logs.host_id = a.host_id
   AND logs.service_id = a.service_id
   AND logs.ctime < a.entry_time
   AND logs.status IN (1, 2, 3)
   AND logs.type = 1
 ORDER BY logs.log_id DESC
 LIMIT 1) AS start_time
```

The table logs is really huge and some friends told me to use a buffer table/database but i pretty knew to this things and i don't know how to do it.

There is an EXPLAIN EXTENDED of the query : [image: Here !]

It seems that he will examined only 2 row of the table logs so why it takes so much time ? (There is 560000 row in the table logs).

Here is all indexes of those tables :

centstorage.acknowledgements :

[image]
centstorage.hosts :

[image]
centstorage.services :

[image]
centstorage.hosts_hostgroups :

[image]
centstorage.hostgroups :

[image]
centreon.hostgroup_relation :

[image]
centreon.acl_resources_hg_relations :

[image]
centreon.acl_resources :

[image]

Comment: Which dbms product? Table and index definitions etc.

Comment: First of all check the execution plan and verify if you are missing an index.

Comment: Do they all need to be `LEFT JOINS`? are the tables sufficiently *indexed*?

Comment: Subqueries are performance killers, you should try to use a derived table instead.

Comment: Just a side note: why wouldn't you want the query to take as much CPU as it can get? Surely that's preferrable as opposed to "oh let's run this query with 10% of CPU and it'll take 10x as long"?

Comment: Query optimisation is kind of an *art*. Execution plan gives the diagnostic, and indexes are the help. But **you** must know what data you want, how you want to use tables and indexes. There are no universal rules in the real world except : *your best friends are the indexes and the execution plan*

Comment: yea can you show  all indexes in these tables, i think you also get bad perfomance in this part on query **AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = MONTH(CURDATE())**

Comment: any other ideas ? i'm still blocked here :/

Answer (score 0):

For `SQL Server` there is the possibility to define the maximum degree of parallelism of your query using `MAXDOP`

For example you can define at the end of your query

```
option (maxdop 2)
```

I'm pretty sure there's an equivalent in `MySql`.

You can try to approach this situation if the execution time is not relevant.

Comment: there is no such thing for mysql, not without going for third party add-ons

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Temporary Table from where condition for acknowledgements, schema  will have column required in final result and used in JOIN with all your 7 tables

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE __tempacknowledgements AS SELECT g.name AS hostgroup
        , '' AS hostname
        , a.host_id
        , s.display_name AS servicename
        , a.service_id
        , a.entry_time AS ack_time
        , '' AS AS start_time
        , '' AS timeperiod
        , a.state AS state
        , a.author
        , a.acknowledgement_id AS ack_id
   FROM centstorage.acknowledgements a
   WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = YEAR(CURDATE())
   AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = MONTH(CURDATE())
   AND a.service_id IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY a.acknowledgement_id ASC;
   ```

Or create using proper column definition

2. Update fields from all tables having left join, you can use Inner Join in update. You should write 7 different update statements. 2 examples are given below.

   ```
   UPDATE __tempacknowledgements a JOIN centstorage.hosts h USING(host_id)
   SET a.name=h.name;

   UPDATE __tempacknowledgements s JOIN centstorage.services h USING(service_id)
   SET a.acl_res_name=s.acl_res_name;
   ```
3. similar way update ctime from logs using Join with Logs, this is 8th update statement.
4. pick select from temp table.
5. drop temp table

a sp can be written for this.

Comment: Seems to be a good way to help me but, i'm still a beginner in SQL complex queries ... so i don't get it all

Comment: Added some example query, may help you get the idea about proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turn `LEFT JOIN` into `JOIN` unless you have a real need for `LEFT`.

```
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = MONTH(CURDATE())
AND a.service_id is not null
```

Do you have any rows with `a.service_id is not null`?  If not, get rid of it.

As already mentioned, that date comparison does not optimize.  Here is what to use instead:

```
AND a.entry_time >= CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01')
AND a.entry_time <  CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 7), '-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

*And* add one of these (depending on my above comment):

```
INDEX(entry_time)
INDEX(service_id, entry_time)
```

The correlated subquery is hard to optimize.  This index (on `logs`) may help:

```
INDEX(type, host_id, service_id, status)
```

Answer (score 0):

WHERE IN is time killer!
Instead of 
**logs.status IN (1, 2, 3)**
use
**logs.status=1 or logs.status=2 or logs.status=3**

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I have SLIGHTLY reformatted the query for my readability reference and better seeing the relations between the tables... otherwise ignore that part.

```
SELECT 
      g.name AS hostgroup, 
      h.name AS hostname, 
      a.host_id, 
      s.display_name AS servicename, 
      a.service_id, 
      a.entry_time AS ack_time,
      ( SELECT 
              ctime 
           FROM 
              logs 
           WHERE 
                  logs.host_id = a.host_id 
              AND logs.service_id = a.service_id 
              AND logs.ctime < a.entry_time 
              AND logs.status IN (1, 2, 3) 
              AND logs.type = 1 
           ORDER BY 
              logs.log_id DESC 
           LIMIT 1) AS start_time, 
      ar.acl_res_name AS timeperiod, 
      a.state AS state, 
      a.author, 
      a.acknowledgement_id AS ack_id
   FROM 
      centstorage.acknowledgements a
         LEFT JOIN centstorage.hosts h 
            ON a.host_id = h.host_id
         LEFT JOIN centstorage.services s 
            ON a.service_id = s.service_id
         LEFT JOIN centstorage.hosts_hostgroups p 
            ON a.host_id = p.host_id
            LEFT JOIN centstorage.hostgroups g 
               ON p.hostgroup_id = g.hostgroup_id 
         LEFT JOIN centreon.hostgroup_relation hg 
            ON a.host_id = hg.host_host_id
            LEFT JOIN centreon.acl_resources_hg_relations hh 
               ON hg.hostgroup_hg_id = hh.hg_hg_id
               LEFT JOIN centreon.acl_resources ar 
                  ON hh.acl_res_id = ar.acl_res_id
   WHERE 
          ar.acl_res_name != 'All Resources'
      AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = YEAR(CURDATE())
      AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME( a.entry_time )) = MONTH(CURDATE())
      AND a.service_id is not null
   ORDER BY 
      a.acknowledgement_id ASC
```

I would first recommend starting with your "acknowledgements" table and have an index at a minimum of ( entry_time, acknowledgement_id ).  Next, update your WHERE clause.  Because you are running a function to convert the unix timestamp to a date and grabbing the YEAR (and month) respectively, I don't believe it is utilizing the index as it has to compute that for every row.  To eleviate that, a unix timestamp is nothing but a number representing seconds from a specifc point in time.  If you are looking for a specific month, then pre-compute the starting and ending unix times and run for that range. Something like...

and a.entry_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-10-01' ) 
and a.entry_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-11-01' )

This way, it accounts for all seconds within the month up to 11:59:59 on Oct 31, just before November 1st.

Then, without my glasses to see all the images more clearly, and short time this morning, I would ensure you have at least the following indexes on each table respectively

```
table              index
logs               ( host_id, service_id, type, status, ctime, log_id )
acknowledgements   ( entry_time, acknowledgement_id, host_id, service_id )
hosts              ( host_id, name )
services           ( service_id, display_name )
hosts_hostgroups   ( host_id, hostgroup_id )
hostgroups         ( hostgroup_id, name )
hostgroup_relation ( host_host_id, hostgroup_hg_id )
acl_resources_hg_relations ( hh_hg_id, acl_res_id )
acl_resources ar   ( acl_res_id, acl_res_name )
```

Finally, your correlated sub-query field is going to be a killer as it is processed for every row, but hopefully the other index optimization ideas will help performance.